# Inverting the value of a numerical field in a MongoDB document

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to figure out how to update all documents in a MongoDB collection, and set the value of a particular field to the negative of its current value.

This is what I have attempted so far.

```
filter = {'field_name': {'$lt': 0.0}}

mapping = {'$set': {'$field_name', -'$field_name'}}

documents = collection.update_many(filter=filter, update=mapping)
```

I am really not sure if I am going in the right direction here as I find it hard to understand the official documentation.

One other possible way I thought to do this might be to iterate over all documents using `find()` with no filter, and to perform an update operation on each document.

It seems that this might not work as intended as documents will be modified which has some kind of undefined behaviour while iterating over a collection of documents?

Asside: If taking an approach via Python which uses `update_many` then it seems to make no sense to use Python at all, and it would be more efficient to run this query on the database directly using `mongosh`.

Comment: you can use the aggregation pipeline with updates https://mongoplayground.net/p/YeUuBSAeCBB . note the `[ ]` as the second parameter. so basically `mapping = [{ "$set": { "field_name": { "$multiply": [ "$field_name", -1 ] } } }]` should work

Comment: @cmgchess I tried to use the mongoplayground to test the query I have just added in the below answer. It fails to compile in the playground, with the error "invalid number". I am not sure why it appears to be running on my computer at home. It might error out in a while or just die. I'll update you when I find out... Thanks for the playground link, I didn't know this existed.

Comment: hmm i have never seen it written like that before. maybe you couldve tested on a smaller dataset :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to cmgchess, this query does indeed perform the correct operations, via `mongosh`:

```
db.pseudodata.updateMany({'field_name': {$lt: 0.0}}, [{$set: {"field_name": {$multiply: ["$field_name", -1.0]}}}])
```

Results:

```
{
  acknowledged: true,
  insertedId: null,
  matchedCount: 127836672,
  modifiedCount: 127836672,
  upsertedCount: 0
}
```

Comment: do a find with `{'field_name': {$lt: 0.0}}` if that returns something that means your qeuery didnt work

Comment: @cmgchess thanks, that seems to be guiding me in the right direction. Will update in an hour or so when its finished running but seems to be good now